# One dimensional and two dimensional motion

Tags: kinematics

I read that 1D motion is straight line motion and 2D motion is the motion when the two coordinates change with respect to time , so what would be the the motion by the graph here

[image: straight line graph]

Comment: 1D motion is the motion where position is described by *one* parameter, not necessarily in a straight line. For example the motion around a circle is a 1D motion, where the angle around describes the position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-D motion would be a straight line motion since there is nowhere else to move. A straight line either y=0 is the x- axis (Abscissa). Think of a ball placed on a real number line. It can only move forward or backward. The equation of motion would be described by the set of coordinates $\{\vec{x}, \vec{v}_x\}$.

In 2-D i.e. on a plane (assuming a flat surface), the ball can move forward and backward in the plane defined by the y=0 or x-axis (Abscissa) and x=0 or the y-axis (Ordinate). The graph here shows a relation for a straight line $y=m\, x +c$, with m=1 and c=0 (for a line passing through the origin). Essentially, its is graph for $y=x$. To describe a motion you need to have a time i.e. t- axis instead of the spatial x- axis.

The motion in this case is of a body moving with a uniform velocity for the 1D motion with the points on the graph $\{t,x(t)\}$. Otherwise, with the graph you have posted, there is no motion because both the axis are spatial dimensions.  Unless, you are plotting a parametric plot with $\{x(t),y(t)\}$. Then in that case you could think that this graph represents the projectile motion for an object thrown at an angle of 45 degrees. The motion being analyzed is for the initial values of x and y where the parabola can be approximated as a straight line.

Comment: ohk thanks much appreciated !

Comment: Parametric equations do not require that this be projectile motion.  x = at  and y = bt would give a straight line.

Comment: I had given an analogy to think visually something like that. I was perhaps thinking in terms of parabolic motion as defined in the high school mechanics. 

Sure, x=t and y=t would give a straight line parameterized by t. This is straight forward and exact.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can rotate your coordinate system so that the motion is along one axis or the other; taking the motion from two dimensions to one.

Comment: So originally if we fix the the coordinate axes then it would represent 2D motion?

Comment: I was wrong.  Rotating the axes is not an option in this case. Parametric  equations would make this a 2D situation.

Comment: but if we would rotate then it can be seen on x axis only so it would be 1D motion . can you pls explain what's wrong in this?

Comment: Your graph represents a functional relationship between x and y.  If you rotate the axes, the relationship remains. The line on the graph would rotate with the axes.